# Why updating global variable does not work in function defined in an imported function

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to understand why the following does not work. I have two files: `app.py` and `config.py` and I am trying to set a global variable by calling a function defined in `config.py` from `app.py`. That simply does not work. Expected output is **Global 2**.

The main file (`app.py`):

```
from config import global_name, init_global
def main():
    init_global("Global 2")
    print(global_name)
main()
```

The secondary file (`config.py`):

```
global_name: str = "Global 1"
def init_global(name: str):
    global global_name
    global_name = name
```

Output **Global  1**. The change of `global_name` value is not visible outside.

What confused me even more is the fact that if I move `init_global()` to `app.py` I receive the expected output of **Global 2**. This version pf `app.py` works fine:

```
from config import global_name
def init_global(name: str):
    global global_name
    global_name = name
def main():
    init_global("Global 2")
    print(global_name)
main()
```

Comment: I have an answer for you. :)

Comment: You can simply write all your config variables in a json or a python file and read all variables in your app.py. https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/

Comment: If you plan to add a lot of variables, you can generalize the helper function I have written.

Comment: @GraphicalDot wouldn't it be easier to add all the values in a dictionary then?

Comment: @GraphicalDot It is a simlipied version for SO. In reality config is a class in a common module and each microservice overwrites it.But for a fun I created a new service which does need to use a specific class and found that problem. Please don't assume solutions, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python always assumes that any variable that is assigned in a function is local to that function. So, when you assign `global_name` to `Global 2`, Python creates a local variable that overrides the global variable. This local variable goes out of scope thanks to Python's garbage collection system, and cannot be accessed from `app.py`. However, it can be accessed by `config.py`! You can, therefore, add a helper function in `config.py` that will return the right value:

```py
# config.py
global_name: str = "Global 1"

def init_global(name: str):
    global global_name
    global_name = name

def get_name():
    return global_name

# app.py
from config import global_name, get_name, init_global

def main():
    init_global("Global 2")
    print(get_name())
main()
```